# Calling data from nested resource to main resource in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, nested-resources

I have a blog app backed with Rails. I have `Posts` and `Comments` tables. Both are connected with `has many - belongs to` relationship, also resources are nested in `config/routes.rb`. In my `posts#show`, I'd like to call comments related with the post. I've written codes like below. But I got some errors like `Couldn't find Comment without an ID`. Here are my codes related with this issue:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.find(params[:post_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @post }
    end
end


# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<h3><%= @post.title.titleize %></h3>
<p><%= @post.content %></p>
<% if @comments %>
    <% @comments.each do |com| %>
        <h4><%= com.title.titleize %></h4>
        <p><%= com.content %></p>
        <hr />
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <p>No Comments Found , <%= link_to 'Add One?', new_post_comment_path(@post) %></p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>


# config/routes.rb
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
```

EDIT:

Now I've used `includes(:comments)` in `posts_controller.rb`:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def show
    @post = Post.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])
    #@comments = Comment.find(params[:post_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @post }
    end
end
```

Also I've updated `show.html.erb` respectively:

```
<h3><%= @post.title.titleize %></h3>
<p><%= @post.content %></p>

<% if @post.comments %>
    <% @post.comments.each do |com| %>
    <h4><%= com.title.titleize %></h4>
    <p><%= com.content %></p>
    <hr />
<% end %>
<% else %>
    <p>No Comments Found , <%= link_to 'Add One?', new_post_comment_path(@post) %></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

And here's new error: 
`PG::Error: ERROR: column comments.commentable_type does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."comme... ^ : SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Post' A...`

Comment: Which line does the new error occur?

Comment: @JasonKim: `@post = Post.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])`

Comment: Can you double check the line? You have where clause and your line doesn't contain it.

Comment: Yep, WHERE clause at database query, but not in controller. I previously have `acts_as_commentable` installed, then removed, rolled it back but it seems not dropped related table.

Comment: Can you check your code to see if you removed `acts_as_commentable` from your model? Also try restarting rails server, just in case.

Comment: I have both removed from `Gemfile` and related model, re-associated models, restarted it but now it can't detect association between `Posts` and `Comments`.

Comment: Add `has_many :comments` in your Post, and `belongs_to :post` in your Comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33434/discussion-between-ekremkrc-and-ermin-dedovic)